# Lisp - Keep words finishing by given letter

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, clisp

I am trying to modify this function in a way that when given a list it will only keep the words ending with a given letter. I have few restriction on what I am allowed to use and needs to keep char,rplacd and length to do it. I'm now having difficulties with the 'length ' part. I initially manage to do it in a way that it would keep all words starting with given letter but I am having trouble doing the opposite in line 5.

`(setq liste '(have read nose art silence))`
I would get the following result
 `(endingwith 'e liste) => (have nose silence)`

```
(defun endingwith (x liste)
   (cond
      ((not liste) nil)
      ((equal
            (char (string (length (car liste))) 0) 
            (char (string x) 0) )
         (rplacd liste (endingwith x (cdr liste))) )
      (t (endingwith x (cdr liste))) ) )
```

Answer (score 2):

Note that the task you have been given teaches a style of Lisp programming which is in the *real world* not used.

- we need to operate of strings, which are vectors of characters
- we can use the standard function `remove`
- destructively changing a list is sometimes useful but can be avoided. See `delete` for a destructive version of `remove`

Example:

```
(defun keep-symbols-ending-with-char (char symbols)
  "returns a sequence, where all symbols end with the given char"
  (when (symbolp char)
    (setf char (char (symbol-name char) 0)))
  (remove char
          symbols
          :test-not #'eql
          :key (lambda (item &aux (string (symbol-name item)))
                 (char string (1- (length string))))))

CL-USER> (keep-symbols-ending-with-char 'e '(have read nose art silence))
(HAVE NOSE SILENCE)
```

Answer (score 0):

Given the limited resources you are given, this calls for a recursive solution. The value of (endingwith 'e liste) should be defined in terms of the value of calling endingwith with the rest of the list, and adding or not the first element if it matches 'e.
Further notice that in your case, length should be used with a string, so use (length (string (car liste))) instead of (string (length (car liste))).
The function would look like this:

```
(defun endingwith (x liste)
   (cond
      ((not liste) nil)
      ((eql (char (string x) 0) (char (string (car liste)) (- (length (string (car liste))) 1)))
          (cons (car liste) (endingwith x (cdr liste))) )
      (t (endingwith x (cdr liste))) ))
```

Answer (score 0):

Some points of style: don't use `(not liste)`; instead use either `(null liste)` or `(endp liste)` which emphasize that `liste` is either an empty list, or that processing has reached the end of `liste`, respectively. Also, use `'()` when the intention is to represent an empty list; use `nil` when the intention is to represent boolean False.

The elements of `liste` are symbols, and `x` itself is a symbol; these symbols need to be converted to sequences so that the final character of the symbol can be assessed. `string` will do the job. But OP code has two problems here: `length` takes a sequence argument, so the value of `(car liste)` must also be converted using `string`; and sequences are zero-indexed in Common Lisp, so the last index of a sequence is one less than its length.

```
(defun endingwith (x liste)
  (cond
    ((null liste) '())
    ((equal (char (string (car liste))
                  (- (length (string (car liste))) 1))
            (char (string x) 0))
     (rplacd liste (endingwith x (cdr liste))))
    (t
     (endingwith x (cdr liste)))))
```

One way to debug programs like this in Common Lisp is to get into the REPL and experiment. When you use a function and it sends you to the debugger, look for lines in that function that may have problems.

In the posted code, `(char (string (length (car liste))) 0)` is the first likely candidate. Try `(car liste)` at the REPL and see if that evaluates to `'HAVE` as expected. When it does, try `(length (car liste))`. That will send you to the debugger again with a type error and a message like

> `LENGTH: HAVE is not a SEQUENCE`.

This suggests that you need to use `(string (car liste))` in the same way that `(string x)` is used in the next line of the original function definition. So, try `(length (string (car liste)))` at the REPL. Now you should see the expected value of 4, but it becomes apparent that the original line of code was a bit jumbled up, because `char` wants the first argument to be a string, and the second argument to be an index. So try again at the REPL `(char (string (car liste)) (length (string (car liste))))`. This again lands us in the debugger with a message like:

> `CHAR: index 4 should be less than the length of the string`.

But that message reminds us that sequences are zero-indexed in Common Lisp, and that the last index of a string of length 4 is 3. So, once again at the REPL: `(char (string (car liste)) (- (length (string (car liste))) 1))`. Now we have success, with the REPL returning the expected `#\E`. Having worked through this problematic line at the REPL, we can now replace the line in the original function definition and see if that works. It does.

Answer (score 0):

```
(defun ends-with-p (end s)
  (string= end (subseq s (- (length s) (length end)))))

(defun keep-ending-with (end strings)
  (remove-if-not #'(lambda (x) (ends-with-p end x)) strings))
```